# Markov chain problem to write a recursive equation

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

write a recursive equation for $a_N(i)$ by considering what happens on the first transition out of state $i$.

Please help me on this problem. I don't know how to start. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denoting with $\tau_i$ the first time we visit a state $i$, we have:
\begin{align*}
a_N(i) &= \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_t = i).
\end{align*}
If we are now in $i$ the next step we are either in $i-1, i+1$ or again in $i$ itself, which gives:
\begin{align*}
a_N(i) &= p_1 \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_t = i, X_{t+1} = i+1)
+ q_1 \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_t = i, X_{t+1} = i-1)
+ r_1 \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_t = i, X_{t+1} = i) \\
&=
p_1 \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_{t+1} = i+1)
+ q_1 \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_{t+1} = i-1)
+ r_1 \mathbb{P}(\tau_N < \tau_0 | X_{t+1} = i) \\
&= p_1 a_N(i+1) + q_1 a_N(i-1) + r_1 a_N(i),
\end{align*}
where the second step follows from the properties of a Markov Chain.
Rewriting now gives the recursion:
\begin{align*}
a_N(i+1) &= \frac{-q_1}{p_1}a_N(i-1) + \frac{1-r_1}{p_1}a_N(i)
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases coming out of state $i$. You either go to state $i-1$ or state $i+1$. What are the probabilities of both cases? What are the probabilities of going to $0$ or $N$ first coming from those states?